# Java OAuth 2.0 Acquire access token via HTTP GET with client Id and secret

Tags: java, http, oauth-2.0, get, httpurlconnection

I want to retrieve with Java 1.6 an access token by usinig HTTP method GET, client Id and secret.

I am using the below code to make it work, but the response i receive is a generic html page instead of the json response with the tokens in it.

Can you please check the code for any mistakes I have made?

Thank you in advance.

```
private String setAccessTokenByClientIdAndSecret() throws Exception {
    String accessToken = "";
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        sb = new StringBuilder("Grant_type=client_credentials");
            sb.append("&Client_Id=").append(msdOauthClientId).append("&Client_secret=").append(msdOauthSecret).append("&Resource=").append(msdOauthResourceUrl);                
                    
            URL url = new URL(msdOathUrl+"?"+sb.toString());
            HttpURLConnection endPointRequestConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
            endPointRequestConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            endPointRequestConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); 
            endPointRequestConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);    

            if (endPointRequestConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new Exception("Error in obtaining an access token. " + endPointRequestConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }
    
            InputStream tokenRequestStream = endPointRequestConnection.getInputStream();
            
            JSONObject tokenRequestResult = new JSONObject(tokenRequestStream);
            accessToken = (String) tokenRequestResult.get("access_token");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }return accessToken;
}
```